# вырезать из строки php

Tags: php, php7

как можно вырезать подстроку с конца до первого пробела, если адрес постоянно меняется

```
Wilhelmstraße 75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *вырезать подстроку с конца до первого пробела*

Элементарно же, с помощью пары строковых функций:

```
$str = 'Wilhelmstraße 75';

$str = ltrim(strstr($str, ' '));

echo $str; // 75
```